# Print python script output correctly in PHP

Tags: php, python

i have a php file calls a script and prints the output like this

```
    $output=shell_exec('/usr/bin/python hello.py');
    echo $output;
```

it prints;

```
    b'total 16\ndrwx---r-x 2 oae users 4096 Jul 31 14:21 .\ndrwxr-x--x+ 9 oae root 4096 Jul 26 13:59 ..\n-rwx---r-x 1 oae users 90 Aug 3 11:22 hello.py\n-rwx---r-x 1 oae users 225 Aug 3 11:22 index.php\n'
```

but it should be like this;

```
    total 16K
    drwx---r-x  2 oae users 4.0K Jul 31 14:21 ./
    drwxr-x--x+ 9 oae root  4.0K Jul 26 13:59 ../
    -rwx---r-x  1 oae users   90 Aug  3 11:22 hello.py*
    -rwx---r-x  1 oae users  225 Aug  3 11:22 index.php*
```

\n characters shouldn't be shown.How can i solve this?

Comment: ok. Problem was python script. I think i should fix this problem from script. The pre methods are working if i use shell_exec('ls -la ./').

Answer (score 5, accepted):

this can be work

```
$output=shell_exec('/usr/bin/python hello.py');
echo "<pre>";
print_r($output);
echo "</pre>";
```

Answer (score 0):

Hope you are trying to print this string in web. 
In that case, PHP may not work with \n characters instead it expects to be `<br/>`
PHP has an inbuilt function which takes care of this transformation of strings.

http://php.net/manual/en/function.nl2br.php

Comment: i tried this but it only converts the last newline character to <br/>.

Answer (score 0):

An alternative would be wrapping the string between `<pre>...</pre>` tags.

Answer (score 0):

It seems like an output from a Python 3 script:

```
from subprocess import check_output as qx
print(qx(['ls']))
```

The subprocess returns bytes and the print function prints their representation as `b'...\n...'` where '\n' are two characters (not a newline).

You could fix it by converting qx() returned value to Unicode and then printing it or by writing the bytes as is:

```
sys.stdout.buffer.write(qx(['ls']))
```